# Text file report is not generating of Availability Databases other Databases during auto backup through maintenance plans in MS SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, availability-groups, maintenance-plans

I have setup `Automated backup` in `SQL Server 2012 Enterprise` Database backup through `'Maintenance Plan'`. I have also configure `AlwaysOn High Availability` to that server .There is `5 databases` in the server, where there is `3 databases` has added `"Availability Database"` in Availability Groups and properly configured with `'secondary replica'` & where `'Availability Mode'` is `'Synchronous commit'` between both server replica.

The `'Maintenance Plan'` backup is configure with `'copy-only backup'` . Because i have added `3 databases` in `'Availability Database'` in availability group and which `'backup type'` is `'full'`. 
I am also attaching the screen shot here
[image]

Whenever i am not selecting `'copy-only backup'` in 'Back Up Database Task' window , as per microsoft alert message ' at promtly windows shows the message like ' This backup type is not supported on a secondary replica and task will fail if the task runs on a secondary replica. For information , see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?Linkid=208213.

whenever i am selecting 'For availability database,ignore Replica Priority for Backup and Backup on Primary Settings'. The message shows like that 'This backup type is not supported on a secondary replica and task will fail if the task runs on a secondary replica. Note: Ignoring the backup priority and availability group settings may results in simultaneous parallel backups if the maintenance plan is cloned on all replicas. for more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?Linkid=208213

So, I have finally select the option like `'copy-only Backup'` due to `copy-only backup` in `'secondary replica'` .

**Note:-** The 'Availability mode' of server is `'Synchronous commit'` mode ( from `'Primary Replica Server'` to `'Secondary Replica Server`').

The schedule backup is running successfully , and 2 backup files are generating in (H: drive).Because out of 5 database (3 database are in full recovery mode, which are added in 'Availability Databases' and other 2 database are in 'simple recovery model'. Only 'Simple Recovery model' database backup file is generating. As microsoft BOL [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh710053.aspx#Restrictions) and MSSQLTIPS Blog documentation [Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2880/backing-up-sql-server-databases-participating-in-alwayson-availability-groups/) `At the time of this writing, only transaction log backups and full backups with COPY_ONLY are supported on secondary replicas`. **But the'text file report' is not generating.**

I am attaching the `'Log file viewer'` history screen shot here
[image]

I am also attaching the `backup preferences`screen window here.
[image]

**Note:-** The Schedule Backup location drive is `'Network Drive'`. In mine case here, it is (H:) Drive. As shown in picture.

I have configure the folder path of `'Reporting and logging'` of my network drive. Here it is (H: Drive). I am attaching the screen shot of that window here
[image]

My `MS SQL Server 2012 Enterprise` version is

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2325.0 (X64)     Jun  8 2012 18:54:43 
>     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Enterprise Edition: Core-based
>   Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

-----------------After Edit ---------------

```
Microsoft(R) Server Maintenance Utility (Unicode) Version 11.0.2325 Report was generated on "Primary Replica instace ID".
Maintenance Plan: AlwaysOn Backup
Duration: 00:00:01
Status: Succeeded.
Details:
Back Up Database (Full) (Primary Replica instance ID)
Backup Database on Local server connection
Databases: Database1,Database2,Database3,Database4,Database5
Type: Full
Append existing
Task start: 2016-09-10T00:00:01.
Task end: 2016-09-10T00:00:03.
Success
```

Note:- Here i have edited my Server instance id as well as Database Name . Because this is my Live server database. Here only Database4 and Database5 file is generated after execution of schedule backup. Which time is showing like this in mail message. Which is

```
Task start: 2016-09-10T00:00:01.
Task end: 2016-09-10T00:00:03.
Success
```

**Note:-I am not including TSQL script here.**

My concern is that What i am committing the mistake here for `'text file report'` generation in `'Primary Replica Server'`.
Any tips or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Out of 5 Databases ,Only 2 database files are created in assigned folder. Which are not added in 'Availability databases' in 'AlwaysOn High Availability Group'.And rest three are 'Copy-only' backup in secondary replica , as per company policy.

Answer (score 0):

Maintenance plans are garbage so this is running exactly as designed. However you don't need to take copy only backups on the secondary, you can if you want to but there's little point.

Any errors here are spurious. If you don't like them then your options are to switch to something professional like Hallengren scripts or Minion Backup; or ignore the errors (while maintaining normal testing of your backups to ensure they're viable).